# cmake project on Windows not picking up Q_OS_WIN

Tags: qt, cmake

I'm porting a legacy Qt project that supports multiple platforms from qmake to cmake, and the source code handles platform-specific code is hidden behind preprocessor macros such as `#if defined(Q_OS_WIN)` and `#if defined(Q_OS_MAC)`.

However, my CMake project seems to not be defining `Q_OS_WIN` or `Q_OS_MAC`, thus leading these platform checks to fail.

Does anyone have any clue what might be behind these missing macros?  Also, how does Qt set these definitions?

Comment: These macros are defined in `QtGlobal` and have nothing to do with either cmake or qmake. [Here is how](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/global/qsystemdetection.h.html#183) `Q_OS_WIN` is defined.

Comment: Also there is no such preprocessor macro named `#is`

Comment: @chehrlic you're right, I meant `#if` instead of `#is`.  I'll update the question.

Comment: @ixSci thanks for pointing out howmacros such as `Q_OS_WIN` are defined.  It seems a possible root cause is that `WIN32` is not being set in the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone stumbles upon this question, Qt defines these macros by including [`QtGlobal`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html).  See [Q_OS_MAC](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#Q_OS_MAC) and [Q_OS_WIN](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#Q_OS_WIN).